# Is this usage of nouns possible?

Tags: word-meaning, nouns, poetry

> The chief **imagination** of Christendom,
>   Dante Alighieri, so utterly found himself
>   That he has made that hollow face of his
>   More plain to the mind's eye than any face
>   But that of Christ. [Source](http://quotes.dictionary.com/the_chief_imagination_of_christendom_dante_alighieri_so)

"imagination" means "one who imagines" here.
But this is not found in any dictionaries.
Is this usage of nouns common?
"beauty" is found in any dictionary, but "Imagination" not.

Comment: It's a great question, but the poetic use of *imagination* is so polyvalent that explication requires moving into the LitCrit domain.

Comment: So you are saying that "the chief imaginator is Dante?"

Comment: Poets are licensed, indeed required, to extend semantics and syntax into areas prohibited to ordinary expository discourse.

Comment: But what about this from Oscar Wilde's story?

Comment: The real drawback to marriage is that it makes one unselfish. And unselfish people are colourless. They lack individuality. Still, there are certain temperaments that marriage makes more complex. They retain their egotism, and add to it many other egos. "temperaments" here means "people" right?

Comment: The chief "imaginer" (in multiple senses) and thereby the chief "thing imagined" not only of Christendom but of himself.

Comment: What about the above quote? "people with those temperaments" right?

Comment: "People of certain temperaments"

Comment: So in some cases, we need to think these nouns that are usually used as abstract concepts can be used in this way?

Comment: Generally, yes; and in poetry you must **always** assume that words are 'polyvalent', are used in multiple senses. That is the poet's job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use nouns in that way, but the word *imagination* is being used here in a different way to modern usage. Here *imagination* is being used as a noun for "the thing being imagined".

Hence the sentence fragment

> The chief imagination of Christendom, Dante Alighieri, ...

means exactly

> Christendom (i.e. the worldwide body or society of Christians)'s chief (i.e. most important) imagination (i.e. idea that has been imagined) is Dante Alighieri (i.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dante_Alighieri).

Be careful though; the word *imagination* is no longer used to mean "a thing that has been imagined" in colloquial English; it is used to mean:

> 1) the faculty or action of forming new ideas, or images or concepts of external objects not present to the senses.
>
> 2) the ability of the mind to be creative or resourceful
>
> 3) the part of the mind that imagines things

Comment: +1 But I think Yeats is employing *imagination* in double sense: the thing imagined AND the person imagining, for the point is that Dante crafted a distinct image of Christianity and in so doing crafted a distinct image of himself.